# How to redirect multiple WCF clients to test servers endpoints?

Tags: c#, wcf, app-config, wcf-binding, wcf-endpoint

We have a product that uses several executables to communicate with different web services via WCF. For every web service, there is a test instance that's accessible under a different domain name. The pattern is always the same, so if `xxx.yyy.zz` is the domain name for the publicly accessible production service, then the test service is accessible under `xxx-test.yyy.zz`. (The rest of the service URIs are identical.)

The service URIs for the WCF clients are currently configured via the `app.config` files, with different defaults for different build configurations (SlowCheetah config transform).

This works fine for testing one of the executables, but it's a major pain when we want to configure an installation of the whole package to only communicate with the test services - we currently have to edit multiple `app.config` files by hand.

What I'd like to do could be easily achieved by either using conditions in, or referencing - say - an environment variable from the `app.config` file. Unfortunately both seem to be impossible.

So my question is: What would be the easiest/most sensible way to redirect our WCF clients to our test servers?

---

**EDIT:**
There are no real obstacles to setting the address via code. Of course we'd have to repeat that code in all executables -- or move it to some shared assembly. Well, maybe that's the most elegant solution after all.

Is there a way to "hook" into the client creation/configuration mechanism globally (=for the whole app domain)? I'm not very well acquainted with WCF, but I guess maybe an endpoint behavior? What I don't know though is where that would have to be registered so that all client proxies will be affected.

Comment: Are there any obstacles, setting your BaseAdress via code? Also, are you using a TestFramework like MSTest or NUnit?

Comment: Updated the question. And no, we're not using test frameworks at the moment. We need this for interactive tests.

Comment: You certainly could install an extension of some type, not sure if it would be a behavior or something else.  WCF gives you many different kinds of extension points.  Extensions can be a bit painful, however, to develop as they are difficult to debug.

Comment: How do you build/deploy your applications? Are you using TFS or any other SourceControl tool? if yes, you could design a second Buildprocess. Another way might be, you use VS's Postbuild-Options and call a simple exe/batch to manipulate your app.config's

Comment: To use the build process would not be practical. We need to be able to switch the "release build" to the test servers.

Comment: @PaulGroke - that's completely practical, depending on what build and deploy tools you're using.  For instance, if you are using TFS Release Management or Octopus Deploy, then they can perform config transforms as part of the release from a single deployment package.

Comment: @Erik Funkenbusch - OK, I guess that wasn't clear enough. It wouldn't be practical *for us*. We don't have any build system like TFS in place, and even if we had, we'd still want to be able to easily switch a complete installation to the test servers - without re-installing.